# MS VC++ 9 pcrecpp.lib linking error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pcre

Just built `pcre-8.34` for MS VC++ under Windows x86, copied the libs (pcrecpp.lib) and the headers (pcrecpp.h, pcrecpparg.h, pcre_stringpiece.h) to their locations and wanted to test a simple code (that works under GNU Linux C++) but I'm getting some linking errors:

```
#define PCRE_STATIC 1

#include <pcrecpp.h>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment(lib,"pcrecpp.lib")

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
  pcrecpp::RE regex("(hello)");
  std::string strBase = "hello hello hello";

  pcrecpp::StringPiece input(strBase);

  std::string match;

  int count = 0;
  while (regex.FindAndConsume(&input, &match)) {
    count++;
    std::cout << count << " " << match << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Building output:

> C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\Coding\pcre>cl.exe /MD
>   /EHsc /O2 pc.cpp Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler
>   Version 15.00.21022.08 for 80x86 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. 
>   All rights reserved.
>
> pc.cpp Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 9.00.21022.08
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> /out:pc.exe pc.obj pcrecpp.lib(pcrecpp.obj) : error LNK2019:
>   unresolved external symbol _pcre_compi le referenced in function
>   "private: struct real_pcre * __thiscall pcrecpp::RE::C ompile(enum
>   pcrecpp::RE::Anchor)" (?Compile@RE@pcrecpp@@AAEPAUreal_pcre@@W4Ancho
>   r@12@@Z) pcrecpp.lib(pcrecpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external
>   symbol _pcre_confi g referenced in function "int __cdecl
>   pcrecpp::NewlineMode(int)" (?NewlineMode@p crecpp@@YAHH@Z)
>   pcrecpp.lib(pcrecpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _pcre_exec referenced in function "private: int __thiscall pcrecpp::RE::TryMatch(class pcre cpp::StringPiece const &,int,enum
>   pcrecpp::RE::Anchor,bool,int *,int)const " (?T
>   ryMatch@RE@pcrecpp@@ABEHABVStringPiece@2@HW4Anchor@12@_NPAHH@Z)
>   pcrecpp.lib(pcrecpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _pcre_fulli nfo referenced in function "public: int __thiscall pcrecpp::RE::NumberOfCapturin gGroups(void)const "
>   (?NumberOfCapturingGroups@RE@pcrecpp@@QBEHXZ) pcrecpp.lib(pcrecpp.obj)
>   : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _pcre_free referenced in
>   function "private: void __thiscall pcrecpp::RE::Cleanup(void)" (?C
>   leanup@RE@pcrecpp@@AAEXXZ) pc.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 5 unresolved
>   externals

Any idea what am I doing wrong? Tried also under VC++ 10, same errors.
Should I include `<pcre.h>` and `#pragma comment(lib,"pcre.lib")` because if I do so the link occurs without any error but seem strange to use the C header and library in the C++ code?

UPDATE:

I did this, and now works, the only problem is: is this ok for C++?

```
#define PCRE_STATIC 1

#include <pcrecpp.h>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment(lib,"pcrecpp.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"pcre.lib")

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
  pcrecpp::RE regex("(hello)");
  std::string strBase = "hello hello hello";

  pcrecpp::StringPiece input(strBase);

  std::string match;

  int count = 0;
  while (regex.FindAndConsume(&input, &match)) {
    count++;
    std::cout << count << " " << match << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Output:

> C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\coding\pcre>cl.exe /O2 /MD
>   /EHsc pcc.cpp /link /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE Kernel32.Lib User32.lib
>   Wininet.lib pcre.lib Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler
>   Version 15.00.21022.08 for 80x86 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. 
>   All rights reserved.
>
> pc.cpp Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 9.00.21022.08
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> /out:pc.exe /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE Kernel32.Lib User32.lib Wininet.lib
>   pcre.lib get_all_proc.obj

Comment: are you sure your "pcre,lib" is built correctly? it seems like it doesn't contain the implementation of the required functions etc.

Comment: If I link against `pcrecpp.lib` doesn't work but if I link it with `pcre.lib` also it works. I tried a precompiled static library also with same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you also need to link against "pcre.lib". If you have a look at the "pcrecpp.h" source code you will see that it includes "pcre.h" so it also uses the "c part" of the library.